# Adding a number to each index of an array and creating a list of new arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have a numpy array `A = np.array([1,2,3])`. I want to add `1` to each element of this array, and return an array with each addition, separately:

My desired output would be:

```
list1 = [[2,2,3][1,3,3][1,2,4]]
```

I have tried the `np.ufunc` method to add my arrays, and using a normal list but both methods add the arrays/lists cumulatively:

```
In[1]:    list1 = []
          A = np.array([1,2,3])
          for i in range(len(A)):
              np.add.at(A, [i,], 1)
              list1.append(A)
              print(list1)

Out[1]:   [array([2, 2, 3])]
          [array([2, 3, 3]), array([2, 3, 3])]
          [array([2, 3, 4]), array([2, 3, 4]), array([2, 3, 4])]
```

This seems like something that needs to be done outside the `for` loop, but I'm not sure what.
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you clarify what you need help with? I'm not quite sure I understand what's going wrong...

Comment: I want to take the array [1,2,3] and add 1 to every index of this array and store them, separately in a new list.
So I want list 1 = [[2,2,3],[1,3,3],[1,2,4]].
But I am getting list1 = [[2,3,4],[2,3,4],[2,3,4]] instead, where the arrays are added each time

Comment: Oh, ok. You're appending it into a new list. Have you tried printing `A` directly instead of appending it to a list and printing the list?

Comment: You said "return an array", then called it `list1`, showed something invalid, now say "in a new list". Can you make up your mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the list.

```py
a = [1,2,3]
out = []
for c, n in enumerate(a):
    newlst = []
    for c2, v in enumerate(a):
        if not c2 == c:
            newlst.append(v)
        else:
            newlst.append(v+1)
    out.append(newlst)
print(out)
```

Output:

```
[[2, 2, 3], [1, 3, 3], [1, 2, 4]]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> A + np.eye(A.size)
array([[2., 2., 3.],
       [1., 3., 3.],
       [1., 2., 4.]])
```